# Can an <a href always on top by using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using supersized plugin to have a rotating fullscreen image background with `<a>`s. But as it sits behind my site content it can't be clicked. So i was wondering if it is possible to  have an `<a>` be swap to top onrollover and be clickable?

Comment: Which thing are you trying to click, the image background, or the links? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the .click() function instead of using href's.

http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$(".floating-links").hover(function() {
    $(this).css({ "z-index": 1000 });
 }, function() {
    $(this).css({ "z-index": 0 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If think you need to check the CSS z-index of your  elements.

```
a {
    z-index: 1000 /* Put in front of other objects */
}
```

Think of the Z-index as layers in Photoshop.